# How to handle undefined function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code is an attempt to create a modular code block, which silently fails in case jQuery (dependency) is not present.

```
(function($, undefined){
    if ( $ === undefined ){
        // Do some stuff here
        return;
    }

    // Rest of the code
})(jQuery);
```

But it throws the following JS error when I don't include jQuery, which is the scenario I really wanted to test in the first place.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I had to resort to a much uglier version of the code.

```
(function($, undefined){
    if ( $ === null ){
        // Do some stuff here
        return;
    }

    // Rest of the code
})( (typeof jQuery !== "undefined") ? jQuery : null );
```

Does anybody know a better way of doing this?

Comment: What's wrong with the ReferenceError? I would not want my module to silently fail like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done like this if for any reason you need it:

```
(function($, undefined){
    if ( $ === undefined ){
        alert('not defined');
        return;
    }

    // Rest of the code
})(window.jQuery); //if property on global object not defined, no error is thrown
```

Comment: Of course, I should have thought about it. Thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know a better way of doing this?

Don't pass it as an argument. The closure still does work:

```
(function(undefined){
    if ( typeof jQuery == "undefined" ){
        // Do some stuff here
        return;
    } else {
        var $ = jQuery;
    }
    // Rest of the code
})();
```

Comment: I agree that this is also a good approach, but I did not want to do that because I was looking for a more concise solution. Thanks for your response.